# Accessing static property as non static - Typo3 mailform extension

Tags: php, typo3

I use mailform extension in TYPO3, but I am getting an error:

> Accessing static property tx_mailform_FE_Handler::$uid as non static in .... line 88,89.

In file where the error is, are these two rows:

```
    $this->configData = tx_mailform_configData::getInstance($this->uid);
    $this->flexform = tx_mailform_configData::getInstance($this->uid)->getFlexform();
```

Here is `getInstance`:

```
public static function getInstance($uid=0) {
    if(empty(self::$instance) || ($uid != 0 && $uid != tx_mailform_FE_Handler::$uid)) {
        tx_mailform_FE_Handler::$uid = $uid;
        self::$instance = new tx_mailform_FE_Handler(tx_mailform_FE_Handler::$uid);
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According the informations given your code should look like this:

```php
$this->configData = tx_mailform_configData::getInstance(static::$uid);
$this->flexform = tx_mailform_configData::getInstance(static::$uid)->getFlexform();
```

You tried to access a static property as non static. Google for self and static keywords.

Hope I helped. :)